# Can't use FirebaseUI with fragments

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to implement FirebaseAuth UI to my app, but I've ran into some issues.

I'm trying to create the FirebaseUIActivity.kt as a fragment, but when I call the support fragment manager it crashes.

```
  supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, FirebaseUIActivity.newInstance()).commit()
```

Here is some code:

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    // Support toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, FirebaseUIActivity.newInstance()).commit()
    }

}
```

FirebaseUiActivity.kt

```
class FirebaseUIActivity : Fragment() {
// Choose authentication providers

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = FirebaseUIActivity()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding: FirebaseUiFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.firebase_ui_fragment, container, false)

    return binding.root

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
}
private val providers = arrayListOf(
    AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
    AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
)

override fun startActivityForResult(intent: Intent?, requestCode: Int) {
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)

    AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
        .build()

    }
}
```

Error:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Check your google-services plugin configuration, the default_web_client_id string wasn't populated.
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.Preconditions.checkConfigured(Preconditions.java:90)
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI$IdpConfig$GoogleBuilder.<init>(AuthUI.java:957)
    at com.example.katzinbetihot.Firebase.FirebaseUIActivity.<init>(FirebaseUIActivity.kt:40)
    at com.example.katzinbetihot.Firebase.FirebaseUIActivity$Companion.newInstance(FirebaseUIActivity.kt:21)
    at com.example.katzinbetihot.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3031)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3191) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1920) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Thanks for your help in advance, Emek!

Comment: They advice to update the classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' inside the build.gradle file of the project over here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1381#issuecomment-456496856 and there are other suggestions there as well. Maybe it would help.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this code line to your strings.xml file

```
<string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">webClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
```

You can get your WEB CLIENT ID from Google Console. Select your project, then go to **API & Services** > **Credentials** and under **OAuth 2.0 client IDs** you will find a ID with the name **Web Client**. Copy and replace the above code with it.

If a Web Client ID does not exist, you can click on **Create Credentials** > **OAuth client ID** then select **Web Application** as the application type on the next page and click create.

Comment: This worked, but I am not sure why :/ . 
Where does this string is used and why ?

Comment: What I found out is that I was missing this plugin in build.gradle(app):
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
I added this in the bottom of the gradle file and commented this line, it worked.
As far as I could see there is a string with the same name inside the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is to help those who have a similar situation as I did (changing `google-services.json` and this error started)

TL;DR: compare your old version to the new version and add the web client id part (can be found in GCP console) into the `oauth-client` section of the new file.

I got the same problem, but it was working fine for a long time until recently when I updated my code with a new `google-services.json`. I reverted to the older version of the `google-services.json` file and it worked.

So I checked into the difference between the two versions, they were only slightly different. Following @Totoo's answer, I went to my GCP console and got my Web client ID (called "Web client (auto created by Google Service)"), I searched the ID in both versions of the `google-services.json` file, and it exists in both files under the `services/appinvite_service/other_platform_oauth_client` section, but only also exists under the `oauth_client` section in the older (working) version of the file. That section looks like this:

```
"oauth_client": [
    ...,
    {
         "client_id": "CLIENT_ID (ends with apps.googleusercontent.com)",
         "client_type": 3
    }
]
```

So, I added this part into the new version of the `google-services.json` file and it worked.

I have only changed the signing SHA signatures in Firebase console (which is the reason I went and downloaded a new version of the file at the first place), so I suspect this is some sort of bug on Firebase's end with them generating the `google-services.json` file, of course, I could be wrong, so feel free correct me.